# Unrecognized Selector - Custom UITableView Section Headers

Tags: uitableview, header, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to create a custom UIView (.h .m & .xib) for a UITableView Section Header.

The aim is that I can pass the Heading title using the following line:

```
sectionHeaderView.sectionLabel.text = @"SOME TEXT";
```

However this always causes the following error:

```
[UIView sectionLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d3f6f0
```

Why does it think this is a UIView when I declare it as DUSettingsSectionView? Here is the code. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

==== CODE ====

From my UIViewController

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 16;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
DUSettingsSectionView *sectionHeaderView = [[DUSettingsSectionView alloc] init];
//    sectionHeaderView.sectionLabel.text = @"SOME TEXT";
return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

From DUSettingsSectionView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DUSettingsSectionView : UIView {
    UILabel *sectionLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *sectionLabel;
@end
```

From DUSettingsSectionView.m

```
#import "DUSettingsSectionView.h"
@implementation DUSettingsSectionView
@synthesize sectionLabel;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DUSettingsSectionView" owner:self options:nil];
    self = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
return self;
}
@end
```

sectionLabel is fully connected inside the .xib and the .xib is set to the DUSettingsSectionView class.

Comment: You show a commented-out assignment in your `viewForHeaderInSection:` method...is that the one that causes the error?

Comment: Yes, if I uncomment the assignment line then I receive the following error: -[UIView sectionLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d3f6f0
2012-06-23 15:36:13.891 du[4108:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView sectionLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d3f6f0'

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"Nib: %@", nibArray);` in the `initWithFrame:` to see what it thinks is being loaded.

Comment: Nib: (
    "<UIView: 0x6b57270; frame = (0 0; 320 16); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6b57470>>"
)

Comment: Right...so it doesn't see the main view of your nib as being an object of your custom class (which I guess is explained by your comment below).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you load the .xib inside `initWithFrame:` method of DUSettingsSectionView but you call `init` inside `(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
To fix it, change `(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` to something like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  DUSettingsSectionView *sectionHeaderView = [[DUSettingsSectionView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  sectionHeaderView.sectionLabel.text = @"SOME TEXT";
  return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem after using initWithFrame:

Nib: (
    "<UIView: 0x6d54d40; frame = (0 0; 320 16); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d54f90>>"
)
2012-06-23 16:16:15.801 du[4545:207] -[UIView sectionLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d54d40
2012-06-23 16:16:15.802 du[4545:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView sectionLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d54d40'

Comment: FIXED: 
Really sorry guys. The problem was purely due to Interface Builder. I had made the connections to "File's Owner". Once I deleted these and re-established the connections through the Views everything worked. The NIB was then loaded correctly. Thanks for the helpful pointers.